# rxjs how do I observe a collection of observables that are not completed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a bunch of observables (typescript `Observable<boolean>`) that each emit multiple times and then complete and I want to remove them from a collection when they complete but while they are still active I need to know the latest values from them. If the set wasn't changing I would have something like this:

```
function all(inputs: Observable<boolean>[]) {
  return combineLatest([...inputs]).pipe(map((values) => values.every(v=>v)));
}
```

but I need to be able to register new observables and remove ones from the list of inputs when they complete...

```
class AssentService {
  all(): Observable<boolean> { /* ??? */ }

  register(input: Observable<boolean>) { /* ??? */ }
}
```

`all` will only be called once (possibly before any register calls) but `register` can be called many times and needs to add that input until it completes (ultimately I need a bunch more than just `all` but I am pretty sure I can figure out the rest of those as soon as I get this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom operator that implements combineLatest with a map and just emits an array of the currently running streams each time any of the streams emit.

This is a high-order operator, so you'd use it like you would `mergeAll()` or `concatAll()` It expects a stream of observables.

```
combineLatestAll(){
  return stream$ => defer(() => {
    const register = new Map<number, any>();
    return stream$.pipe(
      mergeMap((inner$: Observable<any>, index: number) => inner$.pipe(
        finalize(() => register.delete(index)),
        map(payload => {
          register.set(index, payload);
          return Array.from(register.values());
        })
      ))
    )
  })
}
```

You can use this however you like, but this is a simple (if limited) appraoch.

```
class AssentService {
  private _registered$ = new Subject<Observable<boolean>>();

  all(): Observable<boolean[]> {
    return this._registered$.pipe(
      combineLatestAll()
    )
  }

  register(input: Observable<boolean>) {
    this._registered$.next(input);
  }
}
```

Why is this limited? This appraoch multicasts `register`, but you only `combineLatestAll()` on a call after `all()`. So if a consumer calls `all()` first and registers second, this works the way I assume you expect it to.

You could instead cache the most recent result and share it between all subscribers. In this case, `init()` is any block of code that runs when your service starts up. (before your first calls to `all` or `register`)

```
class AssentService {
  private _registered$ = new Subject<Observable<boolean>>();
  private _cashed$ = _registered$.pipe(
    combineLatestAll(),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  /*** init(){ ***/
    this._cashed$.subscibe();
  /*** } ***/    

  all(): Observable<boolean[]> {
    return this.cashed$;
  }

  register(input: Observable<boolean>) {
    this._registered$.next(input);
  }
}
```

Comment: finalize is what I was looking for and didn't know how to find. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mergeAll()` to merge higher-order Observables into the chain:

```
subject
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(),
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: console.log,
    complete: () => console.log('completed')
  });

...

subject.next(timer(1000));
subject.next(timer(1000));
subject.complete();
```

The complete handler will be called only after all nested Observables complete and when the source `subject` completes. You shouldn't need to remove completed Observables because thet are unsubscribed automatically.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ldjj83?file=index.ts

Comment: The reason I need to remove them after they complete is because I need to only be concerned with the "living" subjects. In terms that might be relatable to the world today, each subject I pass to `register` is a voter and may vote whenever I call an election, but if they are dead at that time I don't care about their vote.